# bind data in $ionicPopup

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

[image: when i click on qty than it will be set on ionicPopup]when i click on qty than it will be set on ionicPopup

```
$ionicPopup.show({
    template: '<input type="tel" placeholder="Quantity"  ng-model="data.wifi" >',
    title: 'Enter quantity to change',
    scope: $scope,
    buttons: [{
        text: '<i class="icon ion-close"></i>', type: 'popup-close'},
        {
            text: '<b>Ok</b>',
            type: 'common-btn',
            onTap: function (e) {
                qty = $scope.data.wifi;
                var date = new Date();
                var cartData = {
                    'companyId': compid,
                    'userId': userid,
                    'cartDate': date,
                    'cartStatus': 1,
                    'productId': val.ProductID,
                    'quantity': qty,
                    'cartDetailStatus': 1
                };
                //alert(JSON.stringify(cartData));
                $http.post($rootScope.url + 'UpdateCartQty?margin=' + marginVal + '&roleid=' + roleid, cartData).success(function (data) {
                console.log(JSON.stringify(data));

                $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Message',
                    template: 'Quantity updated successfully !'
                }).then(function () {
                    $scope.items = data;
               //cartid = data.CartID;
                });
            }); 
            return qty;
        }]
    }).then(function (qty) {
        if (qty) {
            console.log('Got quantity ' + qty);
        } else {
            //alert('please enter value');
        }
    }
});
```

I want to bind quantity from my database value so how can not bind the value in ionic popup  it's possible in ionicPopup? any help thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is not so clear. Can you elaborate better it and explain what you expect?

Comment: Thanks for replay #Davide Pastore i wan't bind value in ionic popup in image where quantity is hint text so i want to get quantity value from table

Comment: Do you want to inject the quantity from the $scope to the $IonicPopup? Or otherwise?

Comment: yes i use  $scope varable   #DAVIDE PASTORE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it. This is the content of your controller:

```
var compid = 1;
var userid = 1;
var val = {
    ProductID: 1
};
$scope.data = {
    wifi: "my wifi data"
};

$scope.openModal = function(){
    $ionicPopup.show({
       template: '<input type="tel" placeholder="Quantity"  ng-model="data.wifi" >',
       title: 'Enter quantity to change',
       scope: $scope,
       buttons: [
           {
               text: '<i class="icon ion-close"></i>',
               type: 'popup-close'
           },
           {
               text: '<b>Ok</b>',
               type: 'common-btn',
               onTap: function (e) {
                   qty = $scope.data.wifi;
                   var date = new Date();
                   var cartData = {
                       'companyId': compid,
                       'userId': userid,
                       'cartDate': date,
                       'cartStatus': 1,
                       'productId': val.ProductID,
                       'quantity': qty,
                       'cartDetailStatus': 1
                   };
                   //alert(JSON.stringify(cartData));
                   $http.post($rootScope.url + 'UpdateCartQty?margin=' + marginVal + '&roleid=' + roleid, cartData).success(function (data) {
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
                       $ionicPopup.alert({
                           title: 'Message',
                           template: 'Quantity updated successfully !'
                       }).then(function () {
                           $scope.items = data;
                           //cartid = data.CartID;
                       });
                   });
                   return qty;
               }
           }
       ]
       }).then(function (qty) {
           if (qty) {
               console.log('Got quantity ' + qty);
           } else {
               //alert('please enter value');
           }
       });
};
```

This is the template:

```
<ion-view view-title="My View">
  <ion-content class="padding">
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.wifi">
    <button class="button" ng-click="openModal()">Open</button>
  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```